# Suppress "Stack Exchange" part of site names in the lists of sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com

The lists of SE sites, such as [this one](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=sites) and [this one](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name), used to display clean and short site names:

[image: before]

In the last month or so, these name expanded to include "Stack Exchange":

[image: after]

I don't find this an improvement. The incessant repetition of "Stack Exchange" (140+ times) makes it harder to scan the list, parsing the site names. It's completely redundant, because the page is obviously a list of Stack Exchange sites. And the logic of when "Stack Exchange" is appended is opaque: "Wordpress Development" has it but "Drupal Answers" does not.

Longer site names also tend to linebreak awkwardly:

[image: testing]

What are we testing here, again?

I get that the official site names include "Stack Exchange". But the SE part does not need to appear in every place the site is mentioned (site switcher in topbar doesn't have it, for example).

Feature request: `s/Stack Exchange$//`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

stackexchange.com is inching ever closer (largely thanks to Nick Craver's efforts) to sharing its data models with Q&A sites.

As it turns out, `site.Name` in se.com had a slightly different meaning than `site.Name` does in Q&A. Who knew.

A fix is live now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: This fixed one of two lists pointed out in the questions but not [the other one](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=sites)...