# Suppress “Stack Exchange” part of site names on the list of top users

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

This is a follow-up to status-completed report [Suppress “Stack Exchange” part of site names in the lists of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288642).

The [list of top users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) has recently developed the same problem: incessant repetition of "Stack Exchange", redundant on a page with "Stack Exchange" in large letters on top.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[This wasn't the case last December](http://web.archive.org/web/20161201130728/https://stackexchange.com/leagues), per Wayback Machine.

[According to Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288649), this is a side effect of a data model change, i.e., a bug.

Same bug is present on the [list of moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed that up, along with the Top Askers/Top Network Sites lists in the sidebar on the se.com homepage.

Thanks for the report!